# Using recursion to return a value for each item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion

I'm trying to use recursion in JavaScript to deeply go through an object and return its key and value.

An example of this would be:

```
var json2 = {
  'key1': {
    'key2Nested': {
      'key3Nested': {
        'key4Nested': 'SomeValue'
      },
      'key5Nested': 'unimportantValue',
      'key6Nested': 'SimpleValue'
    },
    'key7Nested': '2SimpleValue',
    'key8Nested': 'unimportantValue2'
  }
};
```

The function will take the above input and return something like

```
['key1/key2Nested/key3Nested/key4Nested', 'SomeValue'],
['key1/key2Nested/key5Nested', 'unimportantValue'],
```

etc for all values.
The problem is I try to use a for loop on all the object's keys and I try to use recursion inside the loop. But the recursion value returns an array, which ends the for loop.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
var makeArray = function(obj) {
      var keysArray = Object.keys(obj);
      var returnArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
          var key = keysArray[i];
          var next_results;
          var path, value;

          if (typeof(value) != 'object' ) {
              value = obj[key];
              returnArray = orderedArray.concat([key, value]);
          } else if (typeof(value) == "object") {
              next_results = makeArray(obj[key]);
              if (next_results) { 
                  for (var j = 0; j < next_results.length; j++) {
                    next_results[j][1] = '/' + key + next_results[j][1];
                    returnArray = returnArray.concat(next_results[j]);
                  }
              }
          } 
          console.log(returnArray);
          return returnArray;

      }

  }
```

The function needs to save the key returned from deeper recursion levels so that it can concatenate it to the path.

Perhaps my algorithm can be improved somehow or I'm thinking of it wrong. Can anyone give some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't `return returnArray` inside the for loop body, but only after it.

Also, some other bugs:

1. The line

   > ```
   > next_results[j][1] = '/' + key + next_results[j][1];
   > ```

   doesn't seem to be right. Your keys are in the first slot of each tuple, and you want the slash in between the keys not before them:

   ```
   next_results[j][0] = key + '/' + next_results[j][0];
   ```
2. In

   > ```
   > var path, value;
   > if (typeof(value) != 'object' ) {
   >      value = obj[key];
   > ```

   you are testing the type of `value` before assigning it (so that you basically use the value from the previous iteration). Move the property access before the condition!
3. The method call

   > ```
   > returnArray = returnArray.concat(…)
   > ```

   doesn't do what you think it does. You're passing in a tuple (array) that you want to get appended to the array, but the [`concat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) merges the two arrays: `[key1, value1].concat([key2, value]) == [key1, value1, key2, value2]`. You want to use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead to get an array of tuples.

In whole:

```
function makeArray(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var returnArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i],
            value = obj[key];

        if (typeof value != 'object' ) {
            returnArray.push([key, value]);
        } else {
            var next_results = makeArray(value);
            for (var j = 0; j < next_results.length; j++) {
                next_results[j][0] = key + '/' + next_results[j][0];
                returnArray.push(next_results[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```